# Replacing a column in a DF from another DF in Julia

Tags: dataframe, julia

Suppose I have two DataFrames `df1` and `df2` as follows

```
df1 = DataFrame(id=["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d"],
    var=[1, 32, 3, 22, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 4, 3])

11×2 DataFrame
 Row │ id      var   
     │ String  Int64 
─────┼───────────────
   1 │ a           1
   2 │ a          32
   3 │ a           3
   4 │ b          22
   5 │ b           5
   6 │ b           4
   7 │ c           6
   8 │ c           7
   9 │ c           8
  10 │ d           4
  11 │ d           3

df2 = DataFrame(id=["a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"],
    var=[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6])

8×2 DataFrame
 Row │ id      var   
     │ String  Int64 
─────┼───────────────
   1 │ a           1
   2 │ a           1
   3 │ b           2
   4 │ b           2
   5 │ b           2
   6 │ c           6
   7 │ c           6
   8 │ c           6
```

The objective is to replace the `var` column in df1 for each `id` with the value of `var` from `df2` for each corresponding `id`, only for those `id` which exist in both `df2` and `df1`

So the desired outcome will look like:

```
DataFrame(id=["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d"],
    var=[1, 32, 3, 22, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 4, 3])

11×2 DataFrame
 Row │ id      var   
     │ String  Int64 
─────┼───────────────
   1 │ a           1
   2 │ a           1
   3 │ a           1
   4 │ b           2
   5 │ b           2
   6 │ b           2
   7 │ c           6
   8 │ c           6
   9 │ c           6
  10 │ d           4
  11 │ d           3
```

Tried the following but they don't work

```
for d1 in groupby(df1, :id)
    replace!(d1.var .= [d2.var for d1 in groupby(df2, :id)])
end

#or

[[d1.var = d2.var for d2 in groupby(df2, :id)] for d1 in groupby(df1, :id)]
```

Will appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
julia> leftjoin!(df1, unique(df2, :id), on=:id, makeunique=true)
11×3 DataFrame
 Row │ id      var    var_1
     │ String  Int64  Int64?
─────┼────────────────────────
   1 │ a           1        1
   2 │ a          32        1
   3 │ a           3        1
   4 │ b          22        2
   5 │ b           5        2
   6 │ b           4        2
   7 │ c           6        6
   8 │ c           7        6
   9 │ c           8        6
  10 │ d           4  missing
  11 │ d           3  missing

julia> select!(df1, :id, [:var_1, :var] => ByRow(coalesce) => :var)
11×2 DataFrame
 Row │ id      var
     │ String  Int64
─────┼───────────────
   1 │ a           1
   2 │ a           1
   3 │ a           1
   4 │ b           2
   5 │ b           2
   6 │ b           2
   7 │ c           6
   8 │ c           6
   9 │ c           6
  10 │ d           4
  11 │ d           3
```

Note that the problem with your data is that `df2` has multiple rows for the same unique `:id` so I run `unique` on it before joining (also note that number of values per group in `df1` and `df2` is not the same).

There are other ways to do it (please comment if you would like to see them), but they would involve more code (iteration through groups etc.). The solution I propose relies on the functions that are part of DataFrames.jl API.

#### EDIT

Performance comparison (first run includes compilation time):

```
julia> repeat!(df1, 10^6);

julia> function sol1(df1, df2)
           leftjoin!(df1, unique(df2, :id), on=:id, makeunique=true)
           select!(df1, :id, [:var_1, :var] => ByRow(coalesce) => :var)
       end
sol1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> function sol2(df1, df2)
           D = Dict(df2[!, :id] .=> df2[!, :var])
           for (i, v) in enumerate(df1[!, :id])
               if v in keys(D)
                   df1[!, :var][i] = D[v]
               end
           end
       end
sol2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> function sol3(var1, var2, id1, id2)
           D = Dict(id2 .=> var2)
           for (i, v) in enumerate(id1)
               if v in keys(D)
                   var = D[v]
               end
           end
       end
sol3 (generic function with 3 methods)

julia> x = copy(df1);

julia> @time sol1(x, df2);
  3.103564 seconds (4.97 M allocations: 685.190 MiB, 4.84% gc time, 80.37% compilation time)

julia> x = copy(df1);

julia> @time sol1(x, df2);
  0.660479 seconds (585 allocations: 409.727 MiB, 23.24% gc time)

julia> x = copy(df1);

julia> @time sol2(x, df2);
  3.462888 seconds (55.36 M allocations: 1.495 GiB, 6.22% gc time, 3.58% compilation time)

julia> x = copy(df1);

julia> @time sol2(x, df2);
  3.382529 seconds (55.00 M allocations: 1.475 GiB, 7.24% gc time)

julia> x = copy(df1);

julia> @time sol3(x.var, df2.var, x.id, df2.id);
  0.380297 seconds (142.77 k allocations: 7.360 MiB, 9.58% compilation time)

julia> x = copy(df1);

julia> @time sol3(x.var, df2.var, x.id, df2.id);
  0.331760 seconds (5 allocations: 720 bytes)
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe @BogumiłKamiński answer is the way to go if you decide to use what DataFrames.jl API has to offer. If you want to try something longer but way faster, however, you might want to try the following:

```
D = Dict(df2[!, :id] .=> df2[!, :var])

for (i, v) in enumerate(df1[!, :id])
    if v in keys(D)
        df1[!, :var][i] = D[v]
    end 
end

Julia > df1
11×2 DataFrame
 Row │ id      var
     │ String  Int64
─────┼───────────────
   1 │ a           1
   2 │ a           1
   3 │ a           1
   4 │ b           2
   5 │ b           2
   6 │ b           2
   7 │ c           6
   8 │ c           6
   9 │ c           6
  10 │ d           4
  11 │ d           3
```

Comment: This will be slower for large tables. To make it faster introduce e.g. `let var = df1[!, :var]` block and also make sure to define `D` inside this block.

Comment: Thanks for this additional solution using dictionaries. I tried this and it works perfectly. I am curious if it will still be faster and memory efficient than the API solution when the DF is very large.

Comment: @Moshi - in my answer I have added benchmark of both solutions and a third solution that uses barrier function (modifying the solution by @AboAmmar) to make things fast.